# If Cell contains value, create Chart in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to make my spreadsheet create pie charts and delete pie charts automatically.

I have 3 columns as follows:

[**States & Licensed Citizens**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFnyF.png)

I would like to code in VBA so that excel creates a pie chart that compares Licensed Citizens to Unlicensed Citizens each time I have a value for each. For instance, when I add the State of Maine, and its values for each column, I'd like Excel to create a pie chart. When I delete the state of Maine, and its values, I'd like the pie chart to be deleted as well.

I couldn't figure out how to create this condition. All help is greatly appreciated!

-Steve

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the sheet module and use the worksheet_change subroutine below.  It will determine if all three columns, A, B and C are not empty.  You could go one step further and check to make sure they are numeric with the isnumeric function.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.colum = 1 Or Target.colum = 2 Or Target.Column = 3 Then
    If Range("A" And Target.Row) <> "" And Range("B" And Target.Row) <> "" And Range("C" And Target.Row) <> "" Then
        DoEvents
        ' make your chart here
    End If
End If
End Sub
```